# can a Windows 7 desktop remote control a MacBook Pro to get greater screen resolution, like on a 2560 x 1440 monitor?

Tags: windows-7, mac, remote-desktop, macbook, vnc

Presently, I use Teamviewer to remote into the MacBook, from Windows.
But it just uses the same resolution as the little Mac's screen.

Is there a way to get more resolution out of a MacBook Pro by remoting in from Windows?

Comment: Windows 8.1 and higher can do this if you use Smart Sizing and Remote Desktop and manually entering the resolution in the RDP file too. But I don't know if mac has the same RDP version, and you do need a windows 8.1 or higher client too. But its awesome. Do keep in mind that although all the pixels are neat, since your primary display can't see them, you will be seeing every other pixel, and as such if the resolution is too high, you simply won't be able to read words anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. It can only use as big of a resolution as what the Mac is set to use for itself. If you had the Mac hooked up to an external monitor with a bigger resolution then you could remote to it using that resolution.